# Contagem de TRUE e FALSE

Tags: r

Tenho um vetor com apenas `true` e `false`, gostaria de saber como faço para contar quantos `true` e `false` tenho neste vetor?

Comment: Tente postar parte do código e a dificuldade que você teve.

Comment: Compartilhe o código fonte se possível.

Answer (score 5):

Use a função summary(),

```
I<-sample (c(0,1), 8, T)
V<-I==1
```

Assim criei um vetor de TRUE FALSE

```
> summary(V)
   Mode   FALSE    TRUE 
logical       6       2
```

Answer (score 3):

Eu usaria a função `table`

```
x <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
table(x)
```

Resultado:

```
x
FALSE  TRUE 
    1     2
```

Answer (score 3):

Além das respostas simples que já foram dadas, há uma mais complicada que pode ser útil quando só precisamos de saber um de ou quantos `TRUE` ou quantos `FALSE`.
Para isso, pode-se usar a função `sum`. Como `FALSE/TRUE` é codificado internamente como `0/1`, podemos somar valores lógicos.

```
x <- c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)    # dados do Marcos Banik
```

Para ver quantos `TRUE`:

```
sum(x)
#[1] 2
```

Para ver quantos `FALSE` negamos `x`, assim `FALSE` passa a ser `TRUE`, isto é `1`:

```
sum(!x)    # negação de x
#[1] 1
```

Comment: E `mean(x)` resulta na proporção de `TRUE` no vetor.

Comment: @TomásBarcellos Certo. Não incluí na resposta porque não era essa a pergunta.

Comment: Claro, era só para somar para futuros leitores.